# algorithm to find the first number in a range that can devided a certain number?

Tags: algorithm, numbers, complexity-theory

I want to optimize my code and I feel there could be a better algorithm for my problem.Here is the thing:
given a range of numbers [lower,upper] and a certain number K(K>=upper>lower),to find the first number in the range that (K % number ==0).what is the best solution for that? I can only come up with the brute force solution but they are too slow for my program.

Comment: What's the maximum value of K?

Comment: @user3386109 sometime can be very large, about 10^9.

Comment: That's not very large. `sqrt(10^9) = 31622` which means that you can easily factor the number into its prime factors. Once you have the prime factors, you can easily compute all possible divisors, and find the smallest one that's in the range.

Comment: @user3386109 Depending on how large is `[lower, upper]`, that may not be an optimization... Huge part of trade-off to optimize this problem. It can also implies to remove any number in `[lower, upper]` that is a multiple of a number already present (ex: for domain [100, 1000] => remove (200, 300, 400, ..., 900, 1000)). I don't think that there is one "big" optimisation, but more probably several minor optimizations coupled together.

Comment: @Wisblade Yes, if you have a reliable heuristic that allows you select different algorithms based on the input parameters (K, lower, upper), then my suggestion is just one of many techniques that can be applied. Even OP's brute force solution will be best for some inputs.

Comment: What is the issue with iterating till `sqrt(K)` and finding all divisors? That should be a simple solution independent of `upper-lower` range

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Let's take a counter-example: K=2^19-1 (524,287, so quite little number), lower=100, upper=110. Brute force can't be beaten on this example, finding prime factors will take some time (in particular because numbers like `(2^N)-1` seems to be quite frequently primes themselves if N is already a prime, see "Mersenne primes"). Here, `(2^19)-1` is indeed a prime number... Iterating until its square root (724.07...) will cost WAY more operations (about 300, more or less) than brute force (which needs only 11 divisions).

Comment: @Wisblade agreed, but if the range was significantly larger, what difference would it make? Easier to have a simple implementation that works in each case (which might not be the most optimal way out every time though)

Comment: @user3386109 Yep, exactly... I don't think that there is a "miracle algorithm" here, not with more precisions on `K`, `lower` and `upper`. But there is a lot of interesting work on creating this heuristic function to chose the (probably) best algorithm for a given triplet `(K, lower, upper)`. A first approach would be: brute force is probably better when `upper-lower+1` is way smaller than `sqrt(K)/2`. On the opposite, if `sqrt(K)` is smaller or equal to `upper-lower+1`, then computing prime factors is probably better.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur That's the problem of optimizations: it should be better _all the time_. Not just in particular cases... Otherwise, it's not optimization anymore (read also comment to user3386109 just above, please).

Comment: It seems like in general it will be hard to know whether looking for prime factors will be faster than brute forcing the range; for small ranges, brute force will almost always win, for large ranges, prime factorization may win; and a combination of the two may be ideal (finding a small prime factor can reduce the range of valid elements from the range, making brute-force more palatable than continuing the factorization). Would a parallel solution that attempts both and uses the factorization results to restrict the search space opportunistically solve your optimization problem?